# Better to use @Autowired or new in Spring test class?

Tags: java, spring, junit

I was wondering about this question by having some trouble writting unit tests for my spring application.

Let's take the following example:

```
@SpringBootTest
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
public class AlbumDTOConverterTest {

    @Autowired
    private AlbumDTOConverter albumDTOConverter;

    @Test
    public void ToEntity_ReturnValue_NotNull() {
        AlbumDTO albumDTO = new AlbumDTO("Summer album", new Date(), "This summer, we have made some wonderfull photos. Have a look!", null);
        assertNotNull(albumDTOConverter.toEntity(albumDTO));
    }
}
```

In order to make `@Autowired` work properly, I am launching a container with annotating the test class with `@SpringBootTest`.

The thing is that I think I am doing this wrong. In my opinion, I'll rather just create a new `instance` of `AlbumDTOConverter` by just using the `new` operator instead of using Spring's IoD.

What do you guys think about this ?

Comment: Depends on what you want to test. Is it a unit or integration test. In the first case create a new instance yourself, in the latter use the container.

Comment: It's just a simple unit test. This is in fact what I thought. Quick answer thanks. I'll vote for you if you make one.

Comment: If you use container only to inject this class, then you can create an instance yourself. But if you need autowire in `AlbumDTOConverter`, then it's another story.

Comment: It is questionable if your SuT or CuT even needs autowire capabilities. On using Mockito as mock framework i.e. `Whitebox.setInternalState(sut, "injectionFieldName", mockObject);` or Springs [ReflectionUtils](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/util/ReflectionUtils.html#setField-java.lang.reflect.Field-java.lang.Object-java.lang.Object-) `setField(sut, "injectionFieldName", mockObject);` allows you to "inject" a mock object into the respective field manually.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For unit tests you don't need a whole container to start. By definition, such units should be tested in isolation. Creating an instance of a class with the *new* keyword is perfectly fine. Even if the class has dependencies on other classes, you can also create them manually and pass to an appropriate constructor of the class.

Note that **the unit is not the same as the class**. The term of the unit is commonly confused among developers, especially beginners. You don't have to rely on the dependency injection in your unit tests. **The container will only increase the time needed to execute the tests** and the long execution time is the main reason why developers avoid running them very often. There is nothing wrong in manually building your dependency tree for a unit under tests.

In the long run, creating similar inputs for different tests might lead to duplication in the test code, but fortunately there are best practices for this problem, e.g. [shared fixture](http://xunitpatterns.com/Shared%20Fixture.html).

Comment: In fact, by testing it myself, the time needed to execute the tests are completly not the same. By creating basic new instances like you said, SpringBoot doesn't have to launch a container.

Answer (score 1):

If you are doing unit test then you should not use @Autowire every time.

Unit test basic says "Unit tests are responsible for testing a specific piece of code, just a small functionality (unit) of the code"

Now question is when to use spring capabilities ?

Sometimes, you'll need to do some unit tests relying on Spring framework like web service call, repository call etc. For example, if you have a repository that has a custom query using the @Query annotation, you might need to test your query. Also, if you are serialising/deserialising objects, you'd want to make sure that your object mapping is working. You might want to test your controllers as well, when you have some parameter validation or error handling. How can you be sure that you are using Spring correctly? In these situations you can take advantage of the new Spring Boot's test annotations.

I thinks this will give better idea.

Comment: Web service calls are for me part of integration testing and not unit testing. For controllers, I would just be mocking their services and inject them in my test class using `@Mock` and `@InjectMock`. I don't think I need to autowire my components to do so and to test my components.